# Isolating/separating vocals from audio by FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I remove the vocals from music via `FFMPEG`

```
ffmpeg -i song.mp3 -af pan="stereo|c0=c0|c1=-1*c1" -ac 1 karaoke.mp3
```

The output is the music without vocals (not completely but fairly good).

I wonder what is the command to make the output separated vocals (vocal only)?

I mean how to save the separated vocals in an audio file?

Comment: Did you find the solution to your question? Needed to do something like this.

Comment: @manishsharma93 not yet

Comment: @slhck sorry, I didn't want to disrespect your effort to answer. Since you mentioned the question is not clear, and it was getting downvoted, I asked a new question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527071/how-to-add-an-still-image-while-combining-multiple-audio-files-in-ffmpeg/527084#527084 to be clear. First, I tried to modify the question, but since your answer would become irrelevant, I decided to ask a new question to be clear. In fact, my struggle was to add the still image in the input map.

Comment: @slhck If you think so, I undeleted the question. The silence was a question but not the major issue. I did it by creating silent input files.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. (Deleted my previous comments.)

Comment: Did you find how it's done yet?